# Tesseract4Android couldn't initialize tesseract API with language

Tags: ocr, tesseract

TessBaseAPI.init() could't initialize tesseract API with language. i have been struggle with this problem for so long. i have try so many solution but it wasn't work. can you guys tell me how to solve this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAdSY.png)

Comment: The language field shouldn't receive the programming language name (or what "plate
" is? a library?), it should receive a human language like "amh" or "eng" or "chi".

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

The language field shouldn't receive the programming language name (or what "plate " is? a library?), it should receive a human language like "amh" or "eng" or "chi".

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html

Comment: plate is model that i retrain from lao model in tessdata folder

Comment: the lang parameter cannot receive any models, it can only receive a human language code

Comment: please refer to its documentation

Comment: for the Lao language it should be language: "lao" https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html Find Lao language on that page

Comment: If you meant something else, please share the full code of your Java app, will be glad to help you :)

Comment: If you have any Tesseract trained model, the Tesseract API doesn't identify that in your app, as you can see on the screenshot you attached. Please share more code to get more context

Comment: i finally can figure out the problem. i was changing method from getExternalStorageDirectory() to getFilesDir() to access data on device and now it have work for me